# Passing Tidymodels glmnet model with categorical variables to gtsummary: not recognising recipe transformed variables

Tags: r, tidymodels, gtsummary

Something is happening in how categorical data in the tidymodels glmnet model is being tidied by gtsummary. The tidymodels team suggested that it seems like gtsummary doesn't account for the transformation from the original variables via preprocessing from the recipe, or maybe the tidying doesn't work that well at all? A reprex of the error is below. And any help is much appreciated!

````r
    library(tidymodels)

    data(penguins)

    my_split <- penguins %>%
      na.omit() %>%
      initial_split()
    
    rec <- recipe(sex ~ species + bill_length_mm + bill_depth_mm,
      data = penguins
    ) %>%
      step_dummy(species)
    
    glmnet_spec <- logistic_reg(penalty = 0.1, mixture = 1) %>%
      set_engine("glmnet")
    
    glmnet_fit <-
      workflow(rec, glmnet_spec) %>%
      last_fit(my_split)
    
    
    extract_workflow(glmnet_fit) %>%
      gtsummary::tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
      gtsummary::as_kable()
    #> Extracting {workflows} model fit with `workflows::extract_fit_parsnip(x) %>% tbl_regression(...)`
    #> Extracting {parsnip} model fit with `tbl_regression(x = x$fit, ...)`
    #> x Unable to identify the list of variables.
    #> 
    #> This is usually due to an error calling `stats::model.frame(x)`or `stats::model.matrix(x)`.
    #> It could be the case if that type of model does not implement these methods.
    #> Rarely, this error may occur if the model object was created within
    #> a functional programming framework (e.g. using `lappy()`, `purrr::map()`, etc.).
    ```
    
    | **Characteristic** | **exp(Beta)** |
    |:-------------------|:-------------:|
    | (Intercept)        |               |
    | (Intercept)        |     0.07      |
    | (Intercept)        |     -1.11     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -2.38     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -3.56     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -4.67     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -5.73     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -6.75     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -7.71     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -9.41     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -11.2     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -12.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -14.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -16.3     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -18.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -19.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -21.3     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -22.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -24.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -26.2     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -27.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -29.4     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -30.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -32.5     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -34.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -35.5     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -37.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -38.4     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -39.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -41.2     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -42.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -43.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -45.2     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -46.4     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -47.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -48.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -49.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -51.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -52.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -53.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -53.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -54.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -55.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -56.4     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -57.1     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -57.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -58.4     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -59.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -59.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -60.1     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -60.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -61.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -61.5     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -61.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -62.2     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -62.5     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -62.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -63.1     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -63.4     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -63.6     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -63.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -64.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -64.2     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -64.4     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -64.5     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -64.7     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -64.8     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -64.9     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -65.0     |
    | (Intercept)        |     -65.1     |
    | bill_length_mm     |               |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.01      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.03      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.04      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.05      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.06      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.08      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.09      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.11      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.13      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.15      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.17      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.19      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.21      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.23      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.25      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.27      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.28      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.30      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.32      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.34      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.36      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.38      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.40      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.41      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.43      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.45      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.47      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.48      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.50      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.51      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.53      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.54      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.55      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.56      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.57      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.58      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.59      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.59      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.60      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.61      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.62      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.62      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.63      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.64      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.64      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.65      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.65      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.66      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.66      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.66      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.67      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.67      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.67      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.68      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.68      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.68      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.68      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.69      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.69      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.69      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.69      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.69      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.69      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.70      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.70      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.70      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.70      |
    | bill_length_mm     |     0.70      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |               |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.03      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.07      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.11      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.14      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.17      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.21      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.24      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.29      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.34      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.39      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.44      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.49      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.54      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.59      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.64      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.69      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.74      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.79      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.83      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.88      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.93      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     0.97      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.02      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.06      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.11      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.15      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.19      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.23      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.27      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.31      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.35      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.40      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.44      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.49      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.53      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.57      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.61      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.64      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.68      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.71      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.74      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.77      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.79      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.82      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.84      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.86      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.88      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.90      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.92      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.93      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.95      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.96      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.98      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     1.99      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.00      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.01      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.02      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.03      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.04      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.04      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.05      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.05      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.06      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.07      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.07      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.07      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.08      |
    | bill_depth_mm      |     2.08      |
    | species_Chinstrap  |               |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -0.25     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -0.53     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -0.80     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -1.06     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -1.31     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -1.56     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -1.81     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -2.05     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -2.29     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -2.53     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -2.76     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -3.00     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -3.22     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -3.45     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -3.67     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -3.89     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -4.11     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -4.32     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -4.53     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -4.73     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -4.93     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -5.12     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -5.31     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -5.47     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -5.61     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -5.73     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -5.86     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -5.98     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.09     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.20     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.30     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.40     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.50     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.58     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.67     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.75     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.82     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.89     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -6.95     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.01     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.07     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.12     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.17     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.22     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.26     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.30     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.33     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.37     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.40     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.42     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.45     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.47     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.49     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.52     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.53     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.55     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.57     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.58     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.59     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.60     |
    | species_Chinstrap  |     -7.61     |
    | species_Gentoo     |               |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.03      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.10      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.17      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.24      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.31      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.37      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.43      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.49      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.54      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.59      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.63      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.68      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.72      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.76      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.79      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.82      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.85      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.88      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.91      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.93      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.95      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.97      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     0.99      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.01      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.03      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.04      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.06      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.07      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.08      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.09      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.10      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.11      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.12      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.12      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.13      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.14      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.14      |
    | species_Gentoo     |     1.15      |
    
    <sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
    
    <details style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <summary>
    Session info
    </summary>
    
```r
    sessioninfo::session_info()
    #> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
    #>  setting  value
    #>  version  R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
    #>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
    #>  system   x86_64, mingw32
    #>  ui       RTerm
    #>  language (EN)
    #>  collate  English_United Kingdom.1252
    #>  ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252
    #>  tz       Europe/London
    #>  date     2022-06-18
    #>  pandoc   2.18 @ C:/PROGRA~3/chocolatey/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
    #> 
    #> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
    #>  package       * version    date (UTC) lib source
    #>  assertthat      0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  backports       1.4.1      2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  broom         * 0.8.0      2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  broom.helpers   1.6.0      2022-01-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  class           7.3-20     2022-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  cli             3.2.0      2022-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  codetools       0.2-18     2020-11-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  colorspace      2.0-3      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  crayon          1.5.1      2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  DBI             1.1.2      2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  dials         * 0.1.0      2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  DiceDesign      1.9        2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  digest          0.6.29     2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  dplyr         * 1.0.8      2022-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  ellipsis        0.3.2      2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  evaluate        0.15       2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  fansi           1.0.3      2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  fastmap         1.1.0      2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  foreach         1.5.2      2022-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  fs              1.5.2      2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  furrr           0.2.3      2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  future          1.24.0     2022-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  future.apply    1.8.1      2021-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  generics        0.1.2      2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  ggplot2       * 3.3.5      2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  glmnet        * 4.1-4      2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  globals         0.14.0     2020-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
    #>  glue            1.6.2      2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  gower           1.0.0      2022-02-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  GPfit           1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  gt              0.6.0      2022-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  gtable          0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  gtsummary       1.5.2      2022-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  hardhat         0.2.0      2022-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  highr           0.9        2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  htmltools       0.5.2      2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  infer         * 1.0.0      2021-08-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  ipred           0.9-12     2021-09-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  iterators       1.0.14     2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  knitr           1.39       2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  lattice         0.20-45    2021-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  lava            1.6.10     2021-09-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  lhs             1.1.5      2022-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  lifecycle       1.0.1      2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  listenv         0.8.0      2019-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  lubridate       1.8.0      2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  magrittr        2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  MASS            7.3-55     2022-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  Matrix        * 1.4-0      2021-12-08 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  modeldata     * 0.1.1      2021-07-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  munsell         0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  nnet            7.3-17     2022-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  parallelly      1.30.0     2021-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  parsnip       * 0.2.1.9000 2022-03-29 [1] Github (tidymodels/parsnip@9ce41c8)
    #>  pillar          1.7.0      2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  pkgconfig       2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  plyr            1.8.7      2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  pROC            1.18.0     2021-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  prodlim         2019.11.13 2019-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  purrr         * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  R.cache         0.15.0     2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  R.methodsS3     1.8.1      2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
    #>  R.oo            1.24.0     2020-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
    #>  R.utils         2.11.0     2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  R6              2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  Rcpp            1.0.8.3    2022-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  recipes       * 0.2.0      2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  reprex          2.0.1      2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  rlang           1.0.2      2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  rmarkdown       2.14       2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  rpart           4.1.16     2022-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  rsample       * 0.1.1      2021-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  rstudioapi      0.13       2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  scales        * 1.2.0      2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  sessioninfo     1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  shape           1.4.6      2021-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
    #>  stringi         1.7.6      2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  stringr         1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  styler          1.7.0      2022-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  survival        3.2-13     2021-08-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  tibble        * 3.1.6      2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  tidymodels    * 0.2.0      2022-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  tidyr         * 1.2.0      2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  tidyselect      1.1.2      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  timeDate        3043.102   2018-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
    #>  tune          * 0.2.0.9000 2022-03-29 [1] Github (tidymodels/tune@6ed30a4)
    #>  utf8            1.2.2      2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  vctrs           0.4.1      2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  withr           2.5.0      2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  workflows     * 0.2.6      2022-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  workflowsets  * 0.2.1      2022-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  xfun            0.30       2022-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
    #>  yaml            2.3.5      2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #>  yardstick     * 0.0.9      2021-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
    #> 
    #>  [1] C:/Users/rmkja/Documents/R/win-library/4.1
    #>  [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.3/library
    #> 
    #> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
````

```
</details>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(small edit)

It looks like an issue in gtsummary:

```
library(tidymodels)

data(penguins)

penguins <- penguins %>% na.omit()
my_split <- penguins %>%
  initial_split()

rec <- recipe(sex ~ species + bill_length_mm + bill_depth_mm,
              data = penguins
) %>%
  step_dummy(species)

x <- prep(rec) %>% bake(-sex, new_data = NULL, composition = "matrix")
y <- penguins$sex

glmn_fit <- glmnet::glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial")

glmn_fit %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) 
#> ✖ Unable to identify the list of variables.
#> 
#> This is usually due to an error calling `stats::model.frame(x)`or `stats::model.matrix(x)`.
#> It could be the case if that type of model does not implement these methods.
#> Rarely, this error may occur if the model object was created within
#> a functional programming framework (e.g. using `lappy()`, `purrr::map()`, etc.).
```

(removed identical html results)

They do not have a `glmnet` method for `tbl_regression()` so the default method is being called. That doesn't work well for this type of object.

Comment: FYI It's on the to do list for the next gtsummary release to have better support for elastic nets. Because this fn doesn't accept typical formula notation and doesn't have the typical  structure of a regression model, it's difficult to support all features in a typical gtsummary regression table (ie grouping dummy variables that belong together, adding a row for the reference group, etc.).